# Select specific word with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which selects the entire contents of an element:

```
function selectElement(element) {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(element, 0);
    range.setEnd(element, 1);
    sel.addRange(range);
    console.log(range);
}
```

Which I call through:

```
selectElement(document.getElementById("input"));
```

If `#input` looks like this:

```
<div id="input">
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit
</div>
```

How can I select characters `0-7`, so that the selection would be:

```
<div id="input">
[Lorem I]psum Dolor Sit
</div>
```

I figured setting the `setStart` and `setEnd` would work, but I can only set it from `0-1`.

Can I select the text inside the node, instead of the node itself?

Comment: Can you just use your function to select entire HTML. Then use regex to parse the string you want.

Comment: No, I need to actually select the text in the browser via `window.getSelection().setRange()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing the whole div node to `setStart`/`setEnd`, that's why you can only select between 0 and 1. You have to pass the div's `firstChild` instead, which is a text node. For example, to select "Ipsum":

```
range.setStart(element.firstChild, 7);
range.setEnd(element.firstChild, 12);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JJ86n/

Note: dealing with ranges cross-browser has always been a mess. It's been a while since I don't deal with it, but last time I checked it seemed a good idea to let a library like [rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) take care of the nasty details.

Comment: Do you know how I could do the same with rangy?

Comment: I don't know, but it's probably on their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select it from the text node inside the element.

```
range.setStart(element.childNodes[0], 0);
range.setEnd(element.childNodes[0], 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with the whole element which is an Object having different objects as properties. To deal with the Strings you must have to get the String(text) sub element first. You can do this by getting getting the child node from the array of elements child nodes. attempting to use a JavaScript String property or method such as length or substr directly on a Selection object will result in an error if it does not have that property or method and may return unexpected results if it does.